# Linked Server - Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server

SQL Server 2005

I can access the linked server with

```
SELECT [id] 
FROM [AFSDB1].[EWMData].[dbo].[eventid]
```

But when I try to access another database with

```
SELECT [id] 
FROM [AFSDB1].[ASPSecurity2].[dbo].[test]
```

I get an error:

> Invalid object name 'ASPSecurity2.dbo.test'

The databases/schemas and tables exist, the above queries were even generated by SQL Server Management Studio while browsing the linked server so there are no typos and I've tried with many tables, all `[EWMData]` tables are accessible and all `[ASPSecurity2]` tables aren't.

There seems to be something special about `[EWMData]` that allows the remote server to access it. I suspect it's a permissions issue but I can't find any differences between the databases. I can browse these databases through the linked server entry in SMS and both databases in the remote server have login 'sa' mapped to user 'dbo'.

Both databases are using the same collation - `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Local login 'sa' is mapped to remote login 'sa'. The remote login 'sa' is mapped to the user 'dbo' for both databases. User 'dbo' is setup the same in both databases. I can't set permissions on table or schema for user 'dbo' in either database (the UI doesn't show user 'dbo'), there aren't any permissions setup in either database anyway.

Comment: Does the user have select privileges on `ASPSecurity2` database? I mean, are you logging in with any different user? And/or are you using Windows Authentication? Take a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Local login 'sa' is mapped to remote login 'sa'. The remote login 'sa' is mapped to the user 'dbo' for both databases. User 'dbo' is setup the same in both databases. I can't set permissions on table or schema for user 'dbo' in either database (the UI doesn't show user 'dbo'), there aren't any permissions setup in either database anyway.